# Не могу понять почему мой код отрабатывает не совсем верно

Tags: javascript, функции, события, dom

Есть функция, она должна выводить текст на страницу из инпута, но если в тексте встретятся символы: "i","o","l" то менять их на числа 1,0,7 соответственно. Мой код рабочий, но перед каждой буквой идет undefined, а потом уже сама буква.

```js
let out = document.querySelector(".out-8")
let input = document.querySelector(".i-8")
document.querySelector(".i-8").onkeyup = (event) => {
  let obj = {
    "i": 1,
    "o": 0,
    "l": 7
  }
  console.log(obj[event.key])
  out.innerHTML = input.value + obj[event.key]
}
```

```html
<div class="out-8"></div>
<input class="i-8">
```

Comment: есть доказательства неправильного поведения?

Comment: " перед каждой буквой идет undefined," --- перед или всё же после?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> перед каждой буквой идет undefined,

такого поведения не вижу. а вот **после** - есть. Логически понятно почему. Потому что в `obj[event.key]` при отсутствующем значении `event.key` в объекте ничего не будет найдено.

Comment: да, все верно: не до, а после, спасибо